# Shell adding a sleep and loop

Tags: shell

how would I make this pause for 10mins then start back up and continuously loop...

```
#!/bin/sh

for page in {1..50}
do
        wget -q -U Mozilla "http://www.domain.com/cat_search/item.html?p=$page" -O - \
         | tr '"' '\n' | grep "^Item photo for " | cut -d ' ' -f 4 >> bpitem.txt
        sleep 15
done
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Enclose the code in a while like this:

```
while :
do
    your_code
    sleep 600
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in an infinite loop like this:

```
while :
do
   for page in {1..50}
   do
        wget -q -U Mozilla "http://www.domain.com/cat_search/item.html?p=$page" -O - \
         | tr '"' '\n' | grep "^Item photo for " | cut -d ' ' -f 4 >> bpitem.txt
        sleep 15
   done
   sleep 10m
done
```